How to resolve a problem involved due to colleague lecturer trying to slander and obstruct work
This is regarding an issue at a university. This university offers computer science and software engineering degrees, and the staff also consists of many software engineering graduates. I'm a Mathematics graduate (please don't misunderstand for explaining, I'm not trying to boast but trying to explain the background details).
There is a module which involves using a lot of concepts from Mathematics, as well as coding. The delivery of the module is conducted by a team of lecturers (where the others are not Mathematics graduates), where the students are divided in to small groups and two lecturers will conduct tutorials for each tutorial group. The lecture session is however done by the lecturer who is appointed as the module leader, by putting all the students in to a same large lecture room.
There have been errors in some Mathematics concepts taught by the lecturers (for example, they say the meaning of one to one and onto functions are the same). I joined to this university newly and initially I've also been put for the tutorial groups together with some other lecturers by mentioning as I'm on training.
It was not possible to get a training on it or identify it's flow because the lecturers who have been doing it have been doing it with errors and there was one lecturer who could write the coding part somehow eventhough she didn't know the Mathematics parts correctly either, but she never discussed it with the entire class so that everyone will learn. Thus, the students couldn't understand exactly well, but they were helpless because of the way they have been controlling.
So that lecturer (say X) who could do the coding part has also tried to tell slanders too about me by saying that I don't take shifts in doing their tutorials. Actually I had been under the impression that I'm supposed to wait and get trained by them as it was mentioned to me but however soon as they have told it I got prepared and took turns in the tutorials. When referring it by gathering other resources as their sessions were not helpful, I understood that it was not difficult for me because I've done Mathematics and some programming subjects in the past.
When I was taking turns I explained the Mathematics concepts too to the class at places where the students couldn't understand. The X has now again has got intimidated. Since the module leader is a visiting lecturer from this semester onwards we have a internal coordinator for this module and that has been appointed to the X.
So she is now instructing us to not to teach any concepts during the sessions. It also feels as if she is acting with a sense of a personal grudge towards me.
There are internal politics up to some extent too in the institute. What is the best course of action to be followed in this type of a situation?
If necessary (if she continues to interfere with my work), what will be the best way to make a complaint regarding that? Or is it not good to complaint?
It seems that they have made upsetting complaints about me eventhough there are faults on their sides too but still gets accepted well also.

If, as CS people, they are dealing with finite sets, then one-to-one and onto do indeed mean the same thing. Are you sure, when you are saying that the staff are intimidated, they in fact aren't just annoyed at your overly complicating the definitions compared to the situations they are dealing with, such as the finite set case I mentioned above? This gives conflicting definitions and confuses the students.  And it's not slander to say you weren't taking shifts. You weren't. You might have a reason, but to the other person they said nothing wrong.

The solution is, unfortunately, probably to wind your neck in, I'm afraid. They are lecturers with decades of experience in their area, you are a new grad student coming in from a different area who thinks they know better. She is not interfering with your work, you are interfering with hers.

@DavidA.Craven Your second comment (and maybe parts of the first) should probably be written as an answer.

@DavidA.Craven, I'm no expert myself on the mathematics but (having looked these terms up...) are you sure "one-to-one" and "onto" (as terms relating to properties of mathematical functions) mean the same things? Also, CS students are perhaps entitled to be taught mathematics concepts correctly (if it is ostensibly mathematics they are being taught), not a nobbled version that is convenient for the lecturer but correct only under unstated assumptions about the context.

Perhaps better on the Academics stack.

@Steve absolutely not in general, but in general we work with functions on infinite sets, say all numbers. Anything in a computer generally only works with a finite set, where they are the same thing. Rather than teach CS undergrads an hour of function theory, the lecturers probably just decided to ignore the distinction.

@DavidA.Craven, perhaps there's some subtlety I'm missing with that logic. From the explanations I've seen of "injective" ("one-to-one") and "surjective" ("onto"), it seems to me that in a computing context, even just for a function which takes a default machine-sized integer and returns the same kind of integer (i.e. no complications with changed data types), that function is not necessarily injective just because it is surjective. There can be values in the arguments to such a function that simply don't appear in the results. How then is there an equivalence between injective and surjective?

Regarding CS versus mathematics: make sure that you aren't dealing with a case where the technical jargon of the two fields simply disagrees, and you are using the wrong definition.

I do not understand one detail: who is responsible for the whole thing? Whose neck will be hurt if trouble appears?

Sounds like you assumed you should wait to be trained did you ever take the initiative to confirm that’s the case? It’s not slander if you were not supposed to wait and actually do the tutorials.

I cannot make head or tails of the question. X is an individual but the author refers to X as “the X” which is extremely confusing

@Steve If I have ten boxes on the left and ten boxes on the right, and I join a line from every box on the left to some box on the right, that's a function. If I miss some box on the right (not onto) then I must have joined two boxes on the left to the same box on the right somewhere else (not one-to-one). The subtlety here is the kind of functions you are thinking of (e.g., double your integer) will overflow or break when given a high number, so are not one-to-one. If double x is 0, is x=0? Or is it 2^31 for an unsigned int, or whatever it needs to be to overflow to 0, depending on the system

@DavidA.Craven, I think my misunderstanding was that "onto" meant simply that some box on the left went to some box on the right (and not necessarily the opposite), with potentially more than one on the left going to the same box on the right. I think what you're saying is that every box on the right must be linked to some box on the left - which makes sense, but that constraint isn't an inherent property of functions as used in computing. For example, a parity function could map every integer argument to either a 0 or 1 result, with the rest of the integers on the right unreachable.

@Steve Absolutely. So a function sending integers to their parity is onto if the set you are mapping to is {0,1}. A map from a finite set to itself that is one-to-one is onto. Examples in CS would be things like finite-state automata, where an input acts by moving you from one state to another.

@DavidA.Craven, but in computing, you're not mapping to {0,1} - you're mapping to the same integer data type on both sides. Or at least, in standard programming languages, this change in the available set is only implicit - it's not marked by the typing system, which continues to explicitly state that the full range of integers is possible on the result side. This is because data types in computing are a property of storage locations, not of values or results. I follow your reasoning now completely, but there's definitely room for confusion here between mathematics and computing. (1/2)

You'd have to carefully explain to a student the difference between the domain and codomain of the function and the implicit difference in the input and output sets, a difference which is not expressed in mainstream programming languages, and the data type of the result which is identical to the data type of the argument, and which is express in all programming languages I know. (2/2)

I am going to humbly suggest that the discussion as to whether the poster is right about mathematics should be taken to chat.

Hi, @DavidA.Craven what made you think that they are the people with decades of experience?  Actually I'm having experience by working at my previous university but they are the fresh graduates. This is related to an old programming language called formal methods and it requires knowing maths unlike other languages.  The students have benefited from it even though others obstructed me.

As a practitioner in software development and with interests in other fields of study, I find there can be infamous differences between how mathematicians conceptualise things and how others do.
However, you are a mathematics graduate, ostensibly teaching a mathematical aspect of the CS course, so presumably you are speaking with some authority on the topic of mathematics if not CS generally.
I think the best approach would be to try and clarify (with whoever is ostensibly managing you) what general activities you should be doing from a working point of view. If it's not possible to proceed for whatever reason, then raise this and seek a response.
And if there is disagreement about the course content you are being expected to teach, or confusion about it, then perhaps ask for some time to discuss and resolve this with the relevant lecturers.
It's worth noting that academic staff are an increasing oppressed workforce, and quality at universities is falling as they become less selective of the students they take and are increasingly governed as capitalist businesses,  so good academics either flee the environment or are hobbled in doing the work necessary to get things right, and a culture of corrupt and manipulative behaviours and crookedness of thinking creeps in.
If you have simply entered such a viperous environment where academic standards are not kept, it may be better to begin seeking different employment rather than hoping for change.

Here is my red pill. Sorry if you wanted the blue, this time you do not have choice.

Computer Science is about Math, and Math is about a "Higher Truth".


Software Engineering is much more pragmatic. Software Engineering is about


They don't need math. They don't need you. You are only the ribbon on the package. The package are they, themselves. You are only the ribbon.

However, also you are there, and not on the Academics SE, whining about your rejected papers in an underpaid math department. I think, the cash plays a role in your decision.
The choice is yours. Looks, if you want the $, you need to live with it.
Believe, it is not the last time in your life, as you can not imagine, what you did again for money.

In my previous life, I was a ribbon. Now I am a package. I still can not confront, what I did for money. I want a revenge. "It was your decision", are singing the angels in my internal ears. Am I crazy? Not at all. I am only angry. So angry that my sense of reality becomes unstable, if it comes in my mind. This world is fcked.
